# how to add a character at the beginning of each element of a string list

Tags: python

I am trying to add the "<" character at the beginning of each element of a list.

```
def names(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        lista[i]+="<"
    return lista
```

Comment: did you mean `lista[i] = '<' + lista[i]`?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing except that `<` goes at the _end_ of each string currently

Comment: Yes. It works fine but the "<" goes to the end and is intended to be at the beginning.

Comment: You modify the list *and* return it. Do you really need both?

Comment: I find a bit odd that the deviation from your desired output lies in the concatenation, yet you did not put a `concatenation` tag, but instead put a `list` and `for-loop` tags. Part of creating a minimal example is seeing whether taking your code block out of the loop results in the same problem. If you do `+=` with a single element, you'll have the same problem; the issue is `+=`, not the for-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
def names(lista):
    return ["<" + item for item in lista]
```

But that will return a new list, instead of changing each item in lista itself. If you instead do want to change the items in lista, you can use the [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
def names(lista):
    for index, item in enumerate(lista):
        lista[index] = "<" + item
    return lista
```

Note that the 'return lista' statement is unnecessary, since lista itself has been mutated, which means all references to it will reflect the changes.

Update:
If you're okay with returning a new list instead of mutating 'lista' itself, an alternative to list comprehension is the built-in [map](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map) function, although I personally find the list comprehension more readable.

```
def names(lista):
    return list(map((lambda x: "<" + x), lista))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your concatenation is the wrong way round.

Try replacing `lista[i] += "<"` with `lista[i] = "<" + lista[i]` (as suggested in the comments). That makes your code into

```
def names(lista):
    for i in range(len(lista)):
        lista[i] = "<" + lista[i]
    return lista
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
def names(lista):
    return ['<{}'.format(elem) for elem in lista]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def names(lista):
   return list(map(lambda i: '<'+i, lista))
```

Testing like this:

```
lista = ["a","b","c","d","e",]
lista = names(lista)
print(lista)
```

will give you this:

```
['<a', '<b', '<c', '<d', '<e']
```